# Which URL pattern is more RESTful for the resource below?

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I have a resource Customer:

```
{
"active": true,
"addresses": [...],
"company_name": "My Products",
"customer_account": "MMM474",
"customer_id": 6163,
"emails": [...],
"phones": [...],
"website": "" }
```

and a related resource Address.

**Which url for accessing Address is more RESTful:**

```
http://domain.tlc/api/v1/customeraddresses/[id]/
```

or

```
http://domain.tlc/api/v1/customers/[id]/addresses/
```

(`[id]` is an ID of particular customer, `customer_id`.)

Comment: There is no "more RESTful" challenge. Application is yours, do whatever fits better to you needs.

Answer (score 3):

definitively option 2. It will allow you to extend the API further and keep it coincide:

http://domain.tlc/api/v1/customers/[id]/contacts/

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the Addresses of a particular Customer I'd go with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

If `[id]` in both cases is the ID of a particular customer, and both URLs return a list of addresses for that customer, I'd say go with option #2.

- `http://domain.tlc/api/v1/customeraddresses/[id]/` looks like a specific customeraddress resource
- `http://domain.tlc/api/v1/customers/[id]/addresses/` looks like a list of all addresses for a specific customer.

That said, they are both equally "RESTful" as they both identify a resource.

Comment: And, in fact, both could be used in any given application to identify the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of an URL as a partition of space into sub-spaces.
Say, you have "Customers" as your root space and underneath, it contains customers which is identified with [id].  Then, under each customer=[id], there are "Addresses".

So, it will lead it to your second option:

```
http://domain.tlc/api/v1/customers/[id]/addresses/
```